# Issue with .htaccess file redirect

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to make my subdomain work and redirect to skykontrol.machinesloveme.com but I can't.
The file redirects successfully to "https://skykontrol.machinesloveme.com/login" but it shows "Internal Server Error" on this site. Without the .htaccess file it works just as expected. I don't now why it fails.
Can you help me???

Also I require that the .php files can be accessed without the extension. I believe I got this right.
Anyways, here is my .htaccess file. I know is a newby question but the help will be highly appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=skykontrol.machinesloveme.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !service [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/skykontrol.\machinesloveme\.com\/login" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^skykontrol\.machinesloveme\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.skykontrol\.machinesloveme\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/skykontrol.\machinesloveme\.com\/login" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Thanks

Already tried with the file, but it shows "Internal Server Error".
Also I don't now why the files automatically is populated with some trash that I didn't code.

Comment: "Also I don't now why the files automatically is populated with some trash that I didn't code" - See this for why: https://serverfault.com/a/963872

Comment: This is confusing ... Now are both http hosts (skykontrol.machinesloveme.com and your "subdomain") really served by the same http server, configured to use the same configuration file you posted above? Otherwise all this makes little sense. But _if_ , then again that second rule does not make much sense, since it always redirects all requests (with a few technical exceptions) to the login page which would result in an endless rewriting loop ...

Comment: _"with some trash that I didn't code"_ - okay, so which part of that trash did _you_ actually write then? Your /login redirect for example is in there _twice_, how come?